# Why does flutter apk command circleci step only work with SSH enabled

Tags: android, flutter, circleci

After upgrading to Flutter 2.28.1 my `flutter build apk` circleci command mostly errors out in the gradle process.  When I rerun the job with ssh enabled, connect to the server and run the same command in the terminal it completes successfully.  It even ran successfully outside a ssh session after rerunning with ssh enabled but not shelling in.  So success twice out of 20 or so failures.  Here is the command in the circle config:

```
      - run:
          name: Package APK
          command: |
            echo "==> Dev Build $CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM <=="
            cd ..
            echo "$PLAY_STORE_UPLOAD_KEY" | base64 --decode > ./upload-keystore.jks
            flutter build apk --build-name ${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM} --build-number ${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM} --release -t lib/main_dev.dart
          environment:
            KEY_STORE_FILE: /home/circleci/workforce/upload-keystore.jks
```

And the DockerFile to define the container:

```
FROM circleci/android:api-30

RUN sudo apt-get update \ 
  && sudo apt-get install -y locales \ 
  && sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && sudo localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

RUN curl https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_2.8.1-stable.tar.xz -o /tmp/flutter.tar.xz && \
  sudo tar -xvJ -C /opt -f /tmp/flutter.tar.xz && \
  sudo chown -R circleci:circleci /opt/flutter && \
  rm -f /tmp/flutter.tar.xz

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/opt/flutter/bin"

RUN curl -sL https://sentry.io/get-cli/ | bash
```

The error is `Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)`.

gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

In order to troubleshoot I added --verbose to the command which didn't uncover the root cause.  It suggests for more info run the gradle command with `Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights`.  How do I do that considering I am running flutter apk not the gradle command directly? flutter tool doesn't seem to pass through those parameters to gradle.  Any other troubleshoot tips I should try?

Comment: Just a quick note, the circleci ssh machine is different from the build one, it's a machine with interactive mode, and because of that you were able to run the command there. CircleCI docs: `Please note that a default CircleCI pipeline executes steps in a non-interactive shell and hence, there is the possibility that running steps using an interactive login may succeed, while failing in non-interactive mode.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, having a container with more RAM, and then adding the environment variables:

```
GRADLE_OPTS: "-Xmx2560m -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs='-Xmx2560m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError' -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx2560M"
```

fixed it.